# how to append all the items in one list using pyqt5 and python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I am able to display and return  all the Items in the list but each item in a separated list.

What i want is to append all the items into the one list.
I will appreciate any help in achieving my goal.

the result that i got:

```
there are 4
```

- ['C:/Users/test/Downloads\cv.docx']
- ['C:/Users/test/Downloads\cv.docx',
  'C:/Users/test/Downloads\Volunteer Card.docx']
- ['C:/Users/test/Downloads\cv.docx',
  'C:/Users/test/Downloads\Volunteer Card.docx',
  'C:/Users/test/Downloads\insta maro\followers.docx']
- ['C:/Users/test/Downloads\cv.docx',
  'C:/Users/test/Downloads\Volunteer Card.docx',
  'C:/Users/test/Downloads\insta maro\followers.docx',
  'C:/Users/test/Downloads\PdfToText-master\examples\text-capture\sample-report.doc']

where what is to  return as the last line Above

what i did until now

## myPDFviewr.py==>Core code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QMimeData)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QColorDialog, QDialog,
                             QErrorMessage, QFileDialog, QFontDialog, QFrame, QGridLayout,
                             QInputDialog, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QPushButton, QMenu,QListWidgetItem)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import pdfviewer
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path
import os
import re
from os import path

import docx

class pdfViewer(pdfviewer.Ui_PdfPreviewWindow):

    def __init__(self,PdfPreviewObj):
        pdfviewer.Ui_PdfPreviewWindow.__init__(self)

        self.PdfPreviewObj =PdfPreviewObj 
        self.setupUi(PdfPreviewObj)
        self.PdfPreviewObj.show()

        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.clicked.connect(self.openfolder)
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.clicked.connect(self.FileListSelected)
        #####################################


    def FileListSelected(self):             # Function to select the desired file from the list in the left pane

        Item=self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem().text()
        print("this is the SELECTED file==>{}".format(Item))

        return Item

    def setExistingDirectory(self):               # create a pop up fileDirectory Dialog Message  in order to select the desired folder.

        self.fileList=[]
        dialog = QDialog()
        options = QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks | QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly 
        Folder = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(dialog, "Open Folder" ,options=options)
        return Folder


    def openfolder(self):            # clear the list & open the folder of the selected path.
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.clear()
        self.checkPath(self.setExistingDirectory())
        self.list_stuff()


    def list_stuff(self):
        ll = []
        print("there are {}".format(self.listWidgetPDFlist.count()))
        for i in range(self.listWidgetPDFlist.count()):
        #print("the row Number =={} || of  Item ==> {}".format(i,self.listWidgetPDFlist.item(i).text()))
        ll.append(self.listWidgetPDFlist.item(i).text())
        print(ll)    

    def checkPath(self,folder):         # Funtion to check the given path for the wanted extension (Files)

        try:
            directory=folder

            whichChecked=""
            for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):

                for filename in files:
                    if len(self.lineEdit_Ext.text())>0:
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("background-color:white")
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("Enter The Filetype Extention Here")

                        if filename.endswith(self.lineEdit_Ext.text()):
                            fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)
                            print(fullPath)
                            self.fileList.append(fullPath)

                    elif self.rdBtn_docx.isChecked() and filename.endswith("docx") or filename.endswith("doc") :
                        self.fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)
                        print("checkpath  Displayed Path => {}".format(self.fullPath))

                        print("=========================================")
                        self.fileList.append(self.fullPath)

                        whichChecked="docx - doc Ext was Selected"

                    if len(self.fileList) > 0:
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("bacground-color:white;")
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("{0}".format(whichChecked))
                    else:
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("background-color:Red")
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("No Ext is Specified")                            


            self.ListFilesInViewer(self.fileList)           # add the list into the  listWidgetPDFlist 
            self.SelectAll.setEnabled(True)

            return folder

        except Exception as e:
            print("this error occure {0}".format(e))


    def ListFilesInViewer(self,Files):              # Function to list all the files in the Left pane 
        for item1 in Files:
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(item1)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.listWidgetPDFlist.addItem(item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PdfPreviewWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    pdfViewerUi = pdfViewer(PdfPreviewWindow)
    PdfPreviewWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## pdfpreview.py==> GUI interface

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:\Users\test\Documents\Python_Projects\tests_scripts\qt_creator\wse_stakckOverFlow\pdfviewer.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.10.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_PdfPreviewWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, PdfPreviewWindow):
        PdfPreviewWindow.setObjectName("PdfPreviewWindow")
        PdfPreviewWindow.resize(767, 502)
        PdfPreviewWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(PdfPreviewWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(749, 0))
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setTabBarAutoHide(False)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.ExportButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.ExportButton.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/export.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.ExportButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.ExportButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.ExportButton.setFlat(True)
        self.ExportButton.setObjectName("ExportButton")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.ExportButton, 2, 2, 1, 3)
        self.groupBoxPDFlist = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.tab)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.groupBoxPDFlist.setFont(font)
        self.groupBoxPDFlist.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.groupBoxPDFlist.setObjectName("groupBoxPDFlist")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBoxPDFlist)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.SelectAll = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBoxPDFlist)
        self.SelectAll.setEnabled(True)
        self.SelectAll.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.SelectAll.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/checkBox.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.SelectAll.setIcon(icon1)
        self.SelectAll.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.SelectAll.setDefault(False)
        self.SelectAll.setFlat(True)
        self.SelectAll.setObjectName("SelectAll")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.SelectAll, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(89, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.listWidgetPDFlist = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.groupBoxPDFlist)
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.setObjectName("listWidgetPDFlist")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidgetPDFlist, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.groupBoxPDFlist, 1, 0, 1, 4)
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.tab)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.groupBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox_2.setStyleSheet("")
        self.groupBox_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.groupBox_2)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setFont(font)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Open.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setIcon(icon2)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(36, 36))
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setCheckable(False)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setDefault(False)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setFlat(True)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setObjectName("pushButtonOpenFolder")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.pushButtonOpenFolder)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.rdBtn_docx = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.rdBtn_docx.setText("")
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/File Format Doc-507x507"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.rdBtn_docx.setIcon(icon3)
        self.rdBtn_docx.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.rdBtn_docx.setObjectName("rdBtn_docx")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.rdBtn_docx)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6)
        self.lineEdit_Ext = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit_Ext.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_Ext.setObjectName("lineEdit_Ext")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_Ext)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_7)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(158, 18, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.formLayout.setLayout(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.groupBox_2, 0, 0, 1, 6)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.lineEditTotalPDFnumber = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineEditTotalPDFnumber.setFont(font)
        self.lineEditTotalPDFnumber.setObjectName("lineEditTotalPDFnumber")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEditTotalPDFnumber)
        self.labelTotalPDFnumber = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.labelTotalPDFnumber.setObjectName("labelTotalPDFnumber")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.labelTotalPDFnumber)
        self.gridLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(502, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem3, 2, 5, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        PdfPreviewWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(PdfPreviewWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 767, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        PdfPreviewWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(PdfPreviewWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        PdfPreviewWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(PdfPreviewWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(PdfPreviewWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, PdfPreviewWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        PdfPreviewWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "XXXXXXX"))
        self.ExportButton.setToolTip(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"right\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">نسخ</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.groupBoxPDFlist.setTitle(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "Files List"))
        self.SelectAll.setToolTip(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Check All Items</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "Search Panel"))
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.setToolTip(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">فتح مجلّد</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "Enter The FileType Extention Here"))
        self.labelTotalPDFnumber.setText(_translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "Total"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("PdfPreviewWindow", "البرنامج"))

import resources_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PdfPreviewWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_PdfPreviewWindow()
    ui.setupUi(PdfPreviewWindow)
    PdfPreviewWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: why no one has an answer for my question until now ?

Comment: Please read up on "minimum viable example", then `edit` your post accordingly. I'm on a mobile, and it won't even *show* me all your code. Clarity and brevity is key in attracting people to spend time in *your* question. Remember, everyone here is a volunteer. The easier you make it for someone to quickly see and understand your *underlying issue* , the more likely you will get an answer. There are thousands of questions posted. Many never get answered. Many are just not worth the trouble to figure out what Q even us. Remember No one is obligated to *give* or receive an answer. All the Best.